# Existence of vector fields

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis

Does there exists two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that the following are satisfied?

> 1. $X(0)= Y(0)= 0$, where $0\in \mathbb R^2$ and for others points
>      $q\in \mathbb R^2$, we have $X(q)\neq 0, Y(q)\neq 0$.
> 2. For any curve $\gamma\in \mathbb R^2$, we have $\langle
>     X'(t),Y(t)\rangle\geq 0$.
> 3. For any curve $\gamma\in \mathbb R^2$, we have $[X'(t),Y(t)]=0$.

What happen if we change condition $3$ to $[X(t),Y(t)]=0$?

Clarification:  As $X$ is a vector field on $\mathbb R^2$, then for any path $\gamma :[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$, we have a map $\tilde{X}(t):[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ by $\widetilde{X}(t)= X(\gamma(t)$,  In above question, I mean $X(t)$ by $\widetilde{X}(t)$ and $X'(t)$ is derivative of this map which can be identified with an element in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I first read that as "one minus $X(0)$...." Probably not best to use the "-" character as a separator that way.

Comment: What does $\gamma$ have to do with $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: What do you mean by $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ and $X'(t)$ and $Y'(t)$?

Comment: @RobertHaraway Doese above clarification make sense

Comment: In questions 2,3 how does the curve $\gamma(t)$ come into the part after "we have..." ?

Comment: @user62445 Yes.

Comment: Maybe I'm misthinking, but if you replace $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(-t)$, doesn't that just change the sign of $X'(t)$?  Doesn't that then mean that your point $2.$ really says that $\langle X'(t), Y(t)\rangle = 0$ for any curve $\gamma$?

Answer (score 0):

I think $ X(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $ and $ Y(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} $ should work.